# Length of values (9) does not match length of index (67)

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

```
Time Open   High    Low Close   Volume  %K  %D  rsi macd                                    
 x    x      x       x    x        x    x    x   x   x
```

The above is the given dataset while importing from yahoo finance. I am getting an error while implementing this code.

```
class Signals:
    
    def __init__(self, df, lags):
        self.df = df
        self.lags = lags
        
    def gettrigger(self):
        dfx = pd.DataFrame()
        for i in range(self.lags+1):
            mask = (self.df['%K'].shift(i) < 20) & (self.df['%D'].shift(i) < 20)
            dfx = dfx.append(mask, ignore_index=True)
        return df.sum(axis=0)
    
    def decide(self):
        self.df['trigger'] = np.where(self.gettrigger(),1,0)
        self.df['Buy'] = np.where((self.df.trigger) &  
      (self.df['%K'].between(20,80)) & (self.df['%D'].between(20,80)) 
                                     & (self.df.rsi > 30) & (self.df.macd > 0) , 1, 0)


   
inst = Signals(df, 5)

inst.decide()
```

what am I getting wrong? any suggestions, please.

Comment: Why don't you use **dfx** instance after create in **gettrigger** function?

Comment: What are you getting wrong? What errors are being logged?

Comment: @AbrarHossain  Length of values (9) does not match the length of index (67). This is the error.

Comment: @Lazyer if i understand correctly. 
                                              def gettrigger(self):
                                                    self.dfx = pd.DataFrame()
??